# How can I repair suction cups on grab bars?

Tags: shower, safety

They stay fixed for a time but then lose suction on one side or both, then moves or drops off the shower wall at any time.

It appears to be the spring compresses over time. Can it be adjusted and made to be 'tighter'?

Comment: What is a "suction cut"? Do you mean "suction cu**p**"?

Comment: It would help to have a picture of the grab bar to ascertain the type of suction cup being used..  "Stayed fixed for a time", do you mean it was holding up good for a period of time and only recently starting losing suction.  or It stayed fixed for a while (one or two days) and then lose suction and this is being repeated constantly?

Comment: If you have hard water, the cups themselves may have acquired a mineral coating that prevents good suction. Try a vinegar soak. That will remove most carbonate deposits. As far as spring adjustments, I've never seen a suction bar that could be dismantled for maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

No suction cups are 100% impermeable, meaning they always leak SOME amount of air, even if at a molecular level, so they will eventually let go. There is no way to change that, you just need to periodically release them and re-apply them, cleaning the cup and the surface as well when you do. The only viable alternative is to permanently affix the bars, not use suction cups. If you are a renter, that may not be a viable option, so just take the Preventative Maintenance approach.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your question is hard to follow but I feel like you really need help to be safe. I think that you have mobility / safety  handles attached to your shower but they keep falling off, and you took a best guess at the reason. Below is another with a possible fix.

A likely the issue is that the shower wall is not fully air tight can let a little air through it and it eventually there is no longer suction on the cups.

One temporary fix that I have been told that is to tape some clear packing tape on the shower in the area of the suction cup to stop the air flow. I have not personally tired this myself so I can not personally vouch for it.

Comment: I would not do the packing tape hack.  You would be substituting the holding power of the packing tape glue on tile in place of the approved suction cup.

Comment: Or they were meant to be grab bars in the first place, lots of people mistake towel racks for grab bars.